# Make mesh face appear more solid

Tags: mesh, vertices

[image: t]

So I'm trying to make a plane mesh out of triangles using subdivision. It "works" fine, however, I want it to look like the left, but when I go to use the mesh I made, it turns out like on the right. They both use the same shader/material in Unity, so I feel it has to be the mesh that is causing this issue. I have no idea on terminology, so I apologize.

Edit: [image: t] Here's what the planes look like flat. As you can see, the one I made (right) has obvious triangles still when flat, however the triangles are almost unnoticeable on the left.

Edit2: [image]

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file so we can have a look? You can do it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately the one I want only comes in a broken file format and can't convert to Blender properly so that's what I'm trying to make my own. An easier way to make my plane would just make a plane, then subdivide it a few times. That's all I'm doing to my plane. I would have no idea of any other way how they made their plane to look like that. edit: I added the .blend anyways!

Comment: Does the plane they use have real height information, or is it all faked by the shader?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett The shader does all the work. Unfortunately I can't tell if the plane they use has any special features compared to the one I make.